# array.each only returns the first value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following command which returns a multiline string and I want to put that into an array and iterate over it, which each line as a single element.

```
def get_mnt_pts
`grep VolGroup /proc/self/mounts | awk '{print $2, $4}' | awk -F, '{print $1}' | awk '{print $1, $2}'`
end
```

the data the command returns and is what the raw input to the array looks like before the split

```
/ rw
/home rw
/usr rw
/tmp rw
/var rw
/var/log rw
```

I have the following code which looks like it takes that data and splits it by newline and puts it into an array.  I then call length on the array to confirm and I can pull out N value but when I do array.each it only ever grabs the first value.

I have a feeling I am dumping the whole string as a single element but then .length return back what I thought it should.  I have checked through the Ruby doc's on arrays and also strings to see if I could figure it out.  I am fairly certain I am creating the array wrong but not sure how.

```
mount_info = Array.new
mount_info = get_mnt_pts.split("\n")

puts mount_info.length  #this returns 6

mount_info.each do |pt|
  puts pt  #only puts the first value of / rw
end
```

When I print out mount_info itself I get the following

```
print mount_info
["/ rw", "/home rw", "/usr rw", "/tmp rw", "/var rw", "/var/log rw"]

puts mount_info
/ rw
/home rw
/usr rw
/tmp rw
/var rw
/var/log rw

print mount_info[4]  #returns back /var rw
puts mount_info[4]   #returns back /var rw
```

Not sure where to look from here, any direction would be great.  The end result is that for each element in the array I want to try to write a file in that directory to confirm the filesystem is in fact writable.  The array contains a list of mount points and for each mount point I will write a Tempfile so the block below will take in the array and iterate through it.

```
def is_rw_test(mount_info)
  mount_info.each do |pt|
    Dir.exist? pt.split[0] || @crit_pt_test << "#{ pt.split[0] }"
    file = Tempfile.new('.sensu', pt.split[0])
    puts "The temp file we are writing to is: #{ file.path }" if config[:debug]
    file.write("mops") || @crit_pt_test <<  "#{ pt.split[0] }"
    file.read || @crit_pt_test <<  "#{ pt.split[0] }"
    file.close
    file.unlink
    return @crit_pt_test
   end
end
```

The code works fine but only for the first element in the array, it won't do it for each though, which is why I think my array assignment is borked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_rw_test(mount_info)
  mount_info.each do |pt|
    Dir.exist? pt.split[0] || @crit_pt_test << "#{ pt.split[0] }"
    # Etc
    return @crit_pt_test # ohai
   end
end
```

You have a `return`, so it returns, and no more iteration via `each`.

If you want to *collect* values, then do something closer to:

```
def is_rw_test(mount_info)
  mount_info.collect do |pt|
    Dir.exist? pt.split[0] || @crit_pt_test << "#{ pt.split[0] }"
    # Etc
    @crit_pt_test
   end
end
```

But if that's the case then an *instance* variable doesn't make any sense.

You need to decide what you actually want to *do*.